# How do i save without a prompt

Tags: actionscript-3, filestream

I found this code snippet i little while ago and found it useful in the app im creating for IOS and i´m trying to save and load this file in AS3 without it asking for a save/load file location and without the device prompting. I am using AIR for IOS

Just to be clear i just want it to save and load to a predetermined location (I.e the app folder).

i have typed in the code below.

```
stop();

// Timeline instances
var textField1:TextField;
var textField2:TextField;
var saveBtn:SimpleButton;
var loadBtn:SimpleButton;

saveBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveClick);
function saveClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // Save the state of both text fields
    save(textField1.text, textField2.text, "SaveData.xml");
}

loadBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadClick);
function loadClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    load();
}

function save(text1:String, text2:String, SaveData:String):void {
    var xml:XML = <xml>
        <text1>{text1}</text1>
        <text2>{text2}</text2>
    </xml>;
    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    file.save(xml, SaveData);

}

function load():void {
    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    file.browse([new FileFilter("XML", "*.xml")]);
    file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, loadSelect);
}

function loadSelect(e:Event):void {
    var file:FileReference = e.target as FileReference;
    file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
    file.load();
}

function loadComplete(e:Event):void {
    var file:FileReference = e.target as FileReference;
    var xml:XML = XML(file.data.readUTFBytes(file.data.bytesAvailable));

    // Assign the loaded XML text values back to the text fields
    textField1.text = xml.text1;
    textField2.text = xml.text2;
}
```

Comment: Don't use **FileReference** class, use **File** class to set the destination file and **FileStream** class to write data. Also, I think the **File.applicationDirectory** is a read-only location (safety measures), you can save things to **File.applicationStorageDirectory**, you don't even need any permission set to do so.

Comment: Would you mind terribly adding your suggested changes to the code i uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Saving file without prompt, or select dialog, or user consent whatsoever. As I mentioned before, no additional permissions required (I think) to write to **File.applicationStorageDirectory** location.

Implementation:

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

function saveFile(fileName:String, fileData:String):void
{
    var aFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);
    var aStream:FileStream = new FileStream;

    aStream.open(aFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    aStream.writeUTFBytes(fileData);
    aStream.close();
}
```

Usage:

```
var X:XML = <xml>
    <text1>{text1}</text1>
    <text2>{text2}</text2>
</xml>;

saveFile("mytest.xml", X.toXMLString());
```

Comment: Looking real good im gonna test this when i get home. Merry christmas